# disable submit button if anyone of checkbox unchecked and input is empty

Tags: angular

I want to Disable submit button if anyone  of checkbox unchecked and input is empty. 
I have tried the following code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ym1rda?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I changed your **[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnsntw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** and fixed it.<br/>
you can use the `some` method of array and check if one of the object has a `checked` property with `'N'` value then disable button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your **[Stackblits demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnsntw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)** and fixed it.
you can use the `some` method of array and check if one of the object has a `checked` property with `'N'` value then disable button.

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  names:[] = [];
  isDisabled= false;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.names = [
      { id:'1', name: 'james', Initial: 'Mr', remark: '',checked: 'Y' },
      { id:'2', name: 'sam', Initial: 'Mr', remark: '',checked: 'Y'},
      { id:'3', name: 'john', Initial: 'Mr', remark: '', checked: 'N' }
    ];

    // added
    this.buttonState();
  }
  myFormSubmit(names){
    console.log(names);
  }

  // added
  buttonState() {
    return this.names.some(val => val.checked=='N');
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<button [disabled]="buttonState()" type="button" (click)="myFormSubmit(names)" >Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function that check the conditions

```
areEnabled(value:any[])
  {
     let enabled=true;
     value.forEach(x=>{
       console.log(x)
       enabled=enabled && (x.checked=='Y' || x.remark)
     })
     return enabled
  }
```

Then you can use

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="!areEnabled(names)" 
   (click)="myFormSubmit(names)" >Submit</button>
```

BTW, what do you not try use ReactiveForms? For me it's the more "natural" way to work with forms and allow more control over the inputs, create custom validators, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to check status and bind it to the disabled attribute of the button.

**component.ts**

```
checkFormStatus(){
    let disable = false;
    // Iterate over names 
    this.names.forEach(
      n => {
        // If not checked and remark is empty 
        if(n.checked=='N' && n.remark==''){
          disable = true;
        }
      }
    );
    return disable;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<button [disabled]="checkFormStatus()">Submit</button>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uq7pzo